# C - Print all prime numbers from 1 to 100 using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, syntax

OK so I got this challenge where I have to print all the primes from `1` to `100`... However there is an error in my code that I am unable to find. Here is how I thought the problem should be done:

- For any number from 3 to 100 check if there is any other number in the primes array that divides it. If there is the number is not prime. If there is not the number is prime and should be added to the array. Pretty simple, right ?
  However it is not working.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int Primes[50] = {0};
    int i, j, k;

    Primes[0] = 2;
    Primes[1] = 3;
    for (i = 3; i < 101; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < 100; j++) {
            if (i % Primes[j] != 0 && Primes[j] != 0) {
                Primes[j] = i;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Primes array : \n");
    for (k = 0; k < 51; k++) {
        printf("%d ", Primes[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `for` loop constraints seem wrong (esp. the inner loop). You'd better check your algorithm, search internet... Your approach needs a third variable (the prime counter) to be used (and incremented, of course) in the inner for loop.

Comment: hi, with `for(j=2;j<100;j++)` followed by `Primes[j]=i;` causes segmentation fault, as j runs till 100 but you defined Primes size to be 50, also you already have Primes[0] set as zero so `Primes[0]=2;` should be `Primes[1]=2;` same for the next line..

Comment: `for(k=0;k<51;k++)` should be `for(k=0;k<49;k++)` as array indexing starts at 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
        if(i % Primes[j] != 0 && Primes[j] !=0)
        {
            Primes[j]=i;
        }
```

You're saying "if the current number is not divisible by the given prime number, replace the given prime number with the current number".  This is not what you want.

You need to check if the current number is not divisible by *any* prime number.  So you need to loop though the list of primes to make sure your number isn't divisible by any of them, and if so add the number to the end of the list.  You can do that as follows:

```
int num_primes = 0;

for (i=2;i<101;i++)
{
    int is_prime = 1;
    for(j=0; j<num_primes && is_prime; j++)
    {
        if(i % Primes[j] == 0)
        {
            is_prime = 0;
        }
    }
    if (is_prime) {
        Primes[num_primes++] = i;
    }
}
```

In the above code, we use `num_primes` to count the number of primes we have so far, and `is_prime` to see if we found a prime that divides the current number.  As you divide each number by a prime, if the remainder is 0 you know the number is not prime and set `is_prime` to 0.  This also causes the inner loop to exit right away.  Then if `is_prime` is still set at the end of the inner loop, you have a prime and you add it to the end of the list.

You also have an off-by-one error in the printing loop:

```
for(k=0;k<51;k++)
```

Since `Primes` has size 50, the largest valid index is 49.  So change it to:

```
for(k=0;k<50;k++)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of assuming the magic number as 25... that is k!=25, we can
replace it with  i<=100.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int Primes[50] = {0};
    int i,j,k  = 0;
    Primes[0]=2;
    Primes[1]=3;

    for(i=0; i<=100; i++) {
        for(j = 2; j<=i; j++) {
            if(i % j == 0 ){
                if(i == j)
                    Primes[k++]=i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Primes array : \n");

    for(int index = 0;index < k; index++) {
        printf("%d\n", Primes[index]);
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issues in the algorithm you used. Use this simple version with issues addressed in the code.

```
int main(void){

        int Primes[50] = {0};
        int i,j,k = 0 /* use for prime count purpose */;
        Primes[0]=2;
        Primes[1]=3;
        for(i=4 /* 3 is already stored */; k != 48; i++) { /* rotate loop until prime count doesn't reaches 48 */
                for(j = 2; j<=i; j++) { /* i is the number you want to check whether its prime or not. SO rotate loop from 2 to "i" */
                        if(i % j == 0){ /* use i%j not i % Primes[j] as you want to check whether i is prime or not */
                                if(i == j)  /* if its a prime numbur j reaches upto i */
                                        Primes[k++]=i; /* store it */
                                break; /* comes out of inner loop */
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("Primes array : \n");
        for(int index = 0;index < k; index++) { /* rotate k times not some random 51 times */
                printf("%d ", Primes[index]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above doesn't actually give what we want, but beautiful code nonetheless. Here is the edited code that gives the prime numbers from **1 to 100**

```
int main(void){

    int Primes[50] = {0};
    int i,j,k = 0 /* use for prime count purpose */;
    Primes[0]=2;
    Primes[1]=3;
    for(i=0 /* 3 is already stored */; k != 25; i++) { /* rotate loop until prime count doesn't reaches 48 */
            for(j = 2; j<=i; j++) { /* i is the number you want to check whether its prime or not. SO rotate loop from 2 to "i" */
                    if(i % j == 0){ /* use i%j not i % Primes[j] as you want to check whether i is prime or not */
                            if(i == j)  /* if its a prime numbur j reaches upto i */
                                    Primes[k++]=i; /* store it */
                            break; /* comes out of inner loop */
                    }
            }
    }
    printf("Primes array : \n");
    for(int index = 0;index < k; index++) { /* rotate k times not some random 51 times */
            printf("%d\n", Primes[index]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Magic number 25 in `k != 25` is unclear.  It makes more sense for code that is doing something "1 to 100" have a 100 in it some place.  Consider a limit derived  from  `n` as in "prime numbers from 1 to n"

Comment: I agree it is hard to follow.. the magic number was 48 and it didn't give what we want so I only changed some numbers until I got prime numbers from 1 to 100.

Comment: Instead of `k != 25`, code could use `Primes[k] <= 100` to iterate until all primes less than 100 are found.  And then print all but the last one.

Comment: I would love to see a code that is easier to follow logically. But so far that is the only code I found that does exactly what we want. I could write it myself perhaps but I haven't got the time to go around doing that yet..